# Why it is not running properly?

Tags: python, cmd, window

I have written code to get list of outdated python module ,I want to upgrade all.For that i need administrative permission. Have a look at code below.

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
process=Popen("pip list --outdated",stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,shell=True,bufsize=1)
data = process.stdout.readlines()
for i in range(2,len(data)):
    temp=data[i].decode("utf-8").split(' ')
    print(temp[0])
    command="runas /user:administrator 'pip install {0} --upgrade'".format(temp[0])
    print(command)
    process=Popen(command,stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,shell=True,bufsize=1)
    process.stdin.write("password".encode("utf-8"))
    print(process.stdout.readlines())
```

Output is not as expected.

[image: Unexpected output is here.]

password is right but i do not know why it's not running.

Comment: Which Windows version? I'd omit all the `runas …` and `password` stuff _inside the script_ and run whole script elevated using `runas /user:administrator  "python \"temp.py\""` instead.

Comment: i use windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. (windows 10 )

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import sys
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,call
import time

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
# shell.AppActivate("Outlook")
shell.SendKeys('runas /user:administrator "pip install pip --upgrade"{ENTER}')
shell.SendKeys("password{ENTER}")
print(shell)
shell.SendKeys('runas /user:administrator "pip install pygame"{ENTER}')
shell.SendKeys("passsword{ENTER}")
```